# Capturing SSL netowork dat with charles proxy with iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I had set up charles to intercept proxy http traffic and now, trying to intercept https traffic. I am using charles 3.11.2 and device with iOS 9.2. I have installed charles root proxy on the system and also installed on the iOS device. I have enabled ssl interception for all pages with wild card "*". When I go to safari and hit a secure webpage, I get `There was a problem communicating with the secure web proxy server(HTTPS)`.

In my charles window, I get the error, `SSL: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?` and notes stating `Exhausted available SSL/TLS protocols, trying with everything enabled`.

Is there any thing which I am misssing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Charles is running with an up-to-date JVM.  I had this same issue and the problem was I had JAVA_HOME set to a Java 6 JRE.  Updating the environment to use Java 8 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the answer here: [Cannot see iOS simulator traffic with charles proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489395/cannot-see-ios-simulator-traffic-with-charles-proxy)

Ensure that ATS is present for debug builds as commented in the shared thread

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).