# Charles Proxy iOS stuck on installing the profile

Tags: ios, proxy, charles-proxy

Hello and greetings everyone.

I was using Charles Proxy on Mac & iPhone and I started to have some issues. So I removed all certificates/profiles from both devices. Now I cannot install it.

1. Installed Root Certificate on Mac.
2. Connected both devices to the same WiFi.
3. Configured WiFi Proxy on iOS device to Charles:
   Server: 
   Port: 8888
4. Open Safari on the iOS device:
5. Browsed to chls.pro/ssl to download and install the certificate

**BUT** I'm stuck here. Because it doesn't install the profile. I have the same issue when I try it on Android devices. But iPhone is my priority for now.

What should I do?

MacBook Pro - Intel
MacOS Version: 11.5.2
iPhone Xs Max
iOS Version: 12.1

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons why your iPhone could not connect to Charles Proxy app. Here are the top two reasons:

1. Your iPhone/Android is using VPN => Turn it off.
2. Your Macbook blocks all incoming traffic on Firewall. Please open System Preference -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall tab -> Turn it off.

If it doesn't work, you might check this [troubleshooting](https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/my-ios-devices-couldnt-connect-to-proxyman-via-proxy#1-problems) page which I've collected all possible problems and how to fix them when using Proxyman, which is a similar app with Charles Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found the answer here:

[Charles proxy doesn't work on my IOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399670/charles-proxy-doesnt-work-on-my-ios-device)

```
4 Install Charles CA Certificate on your device: 
iOS ≥ 10.3: Setting app > General > Profiles > Select Charles CA > Install
iOS ≥ 12.2: Setting app > Profiles Downloaded > Select Charles CA > Install
```

From then you can continue with the instructions as per Charles, which is to go to Trusted Certificates and tell iOS to trust the certificate.